# i want to reload the page on aspxgridview rowupdating event

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

Iam using Devexpress aspxgridview control in asp.net. I want to reload the page on aspxgridview_row updating event.

I tried response.redirect(""); but it shows /Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback./

So, what is the right method to reload the page on rowupdating event.

Note:
Iam using gridview with in the gridview (mastergrid and gridview in the detailrow of mastergrid). now i want to reload the page on row_updating event of detailgridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ASPxGridView [ASPxGridView.EnableCallBacks](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_EnableCallBackstopic) Property is set to `true` then you can not use `Response.Redirect.`

Use [ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesASPxWebControl_RedirectOnCallbacktopic) Method to redirect page to another `Url` while process `callback`.

```
ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload complete page you can set ClientSideEvents.EndCallback handler like this:

```cs
protected void Grid_RowUpdatingEvent(object sender, ASPxDataUpdatingEventArgs e) 
{
    ASPxGridView grid = (ASPxGridView)sender;
    grid.JSProperties["cp_RefreshPage"] = true;

    grid.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = 
        @"function(s,e)
        {
            if(s.cp_RefreshPage!=null)
            {
                window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                s.cp_RefreshPage=null;
            }
        };";
}
```

If you need to refresh both grids and not the whole page it is better to use gridClientInstanceName.Refresh() instead of location.replace. http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_Refreshtopic

Alternatively, you can use solution described in this ticket: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S134916.aspx

Comment: you probably defined event handler in page. I changed answer to suite your needs. Try with updated code.